# How to bind image and video in same datalist?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My question is I have two coloumns video_url and image_src
I want bind this in single datalist at same time aspx code

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function dd() {
                var s = '<%#Eval("Video_url")%>';

                if (s == "") {
                    "<a href='Client_website/raymond_shop.aspx'><img style='width: 245px; height: 220px;' src=Ads_image/" + <%#Eval("Image")%> +"/></a>";
                }
                else {
                    " <iframe frameborder='0' allowfullscreen='' src='" +<%#("Video_url")%> +"' style='width: 245px; height: 180px;' id='Iframe2'></iframe>";
                }
            }
            </script>
        <%--   <iframe frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/icr2X5aKRMU" style="width: 245px; height: 180px;" id="Iframe2"></iframe>--%>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

C# code

```
public void fi()
{
    ds = cat.fill("tbl_Main_ads where status=1");
    DataList2.DataSource = ds;
    DataList2.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Please reformat your code. Good formatting is always your friend. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: what is the solutions for this